# Inject dll process

Tags: c#

Подскажите каким способом еще возможно заинжектить dll .net кроме mono?
Нужно чтобы dll загрузилась и выполнила void Loader из Class Initialize.
Нужно это для того,чтобы с сервера загружать в клиент dll и далее уже инжектить в Assambly лист

Comment: Какую глобальную задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Answer (score 0):

Вручную.
Ну во-первых надо чтобы клиент тыкнул в окошко UAC, когда будет запускаться инъектор (иначе открывать чужой процесс с правами на чтение-запись-создание удаленного потока как минимум ему не дадут).

Во-вторых, ниже я привожу нужный вам код. На C# писать будет тяжеловато, придется делать dllimport для нужных системных вызовов, мучаться с типами и т.д., я бы написал код на Си, собрал в dll и подключал эту dll к проекту на шарпе.

Портянка нужного вам кода на сишке + винапи в общем тривиальна:
*** Здесь и далее код с функциями винапи в скобках, описывающий ход решения ***

Получить имя процесса, в который вы будете внедряться;

Получить снимок процессов скажем CreateToolHelp32Snapshot 
(это функция-обертка над NtQuerySystemInformation, так что решайте, использовать её или нет. но я бы использовал);

Пробегая по полученному списку процессов (для этого есть Process32Next), найти нужный по имени;

Сделать себе SeDebugPrivilege (процессу инъектора, это необязательный пункт);

Открыть найденный процесс с правами на запись в память и создание удаленного потока (OpenProcess, нужные флаги выглядят так: PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_WRITE);

Далее потребуется некая предварительная подготовка. 
Получите адрес kernel32.dll:LoadLibrary в инъекторе, и этот же адрес (по крайней мере для 32бит систем, в 64бит придется еще обходить/отключать ASLR) будет в чужом процессе также указывать на kernel32.dll. 
Получите абсолютный путь до своей dll. В моем случае dll лежит в папке с инъектором, так что я делаю GetModuleFileName в инъекторе, получившийся путь парсю с конца до первого вхождения '\' и вставляю "\myDll.dll".

Выделите память в чужом адресном пространстве (VirtualAllocEx), вам нужна память под адрес своей dll. 
Запишите туда адрес своей dll (WriteProcessMemory).

Создайте и запустите удаленный поток (CreateRemoteThread), в аргументах у него должен лежать адрес kernel32.dll:LoadLibrary, и указатель на строку с путем до dll - не в вашем процессе, а то что вернула VirtualAllocEx, она возвращает адрес в чужом адресном пространстве.

Удаленный поток вызовет в чужом процессе LoadLibrary, та загрузит вашу DLL, DLL выполнит свою точку входа. Задача решена.

Comment: Vac не работает с данной игрой )

Comment: игру в 2014 удалили из steam - но люди все равно играют на пиратке

Comment: Я хотел сказать UAC =(

Comment: Бывает ) - а точно будит работать?Просто если брать какой нибудь готовый инжектор dll не инжектится - если брать mono - все работает

Comment: такой вопрос - допустим я написал свою dll на C++ и хочу импортировать к себе в проект - куда мне положить мою C++ dll?

Comment: Не будет работать значит надо искать ошибку.
В проект ты dll особо не поимпортируешь, в проекте у тебя должен лежать заголовочный файл с нужными символами из библиотеки (с прототипами нужных функций, чтобы компилятор знал какой код ему генерировать для функций которых он в глаза не видел).
DLL неважно на каком языке будет загружена программой в ходе выполнения программы, искать её программа будет сначала в своем рабочем каталоге (программа в C:\Games\NFS\game.exe, DLL в C:\Games\NFS\example.dll к примеру), затем по системным папкам и каталогам среды.